# Can't reference the elements in my JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using $.parseJSON() on a JSON string to output an object and now I'm trying to access the elements inside my object but it doesn't seem to be working. The structure of the object looks like this:

```
{"16": 
  {"day": 
    {"indices": [], "raw": {"negative": [], "positive": [], "sentiment": [], "volume": []}, "smoothed": {"negative": [], "positive": [], "sentiment": [], "volume": []}}, 
  "hour": 
    {"indices": [], "raw": {"negative": [], "positive": [], "sentiment": [], "volume": []}, "smoothed": {"negative": [], "positive": [], "sentiment": [], "volume": []}}}}
```

I've taken the data out of the structure to save space but I'm trying to access it like this:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(json.day.indices[0]);
```

I've tried referencing it a couple of different ways now but can't get it to output anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
alert(json['16'].day.indices[0]);
```

because it looks like `day` is not a direct property of `json` it is a child of a property called `16`

Comment: Damn it, you're right, I knew I was doing something silly. I'll give you the answer after the 10 mins is up :)